# Error: The method evm_increaseTime does not exist/is not available

Tags: web3js, truffle, openzeppelin, rinkeby

While testing a time-dependent smart contract with truffle, I tried to use openzeppelin test-helpers' increaseTo function to forward time.

I required the dependency as shown below,

```
const { time } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');
```

And added the following lines to the code.

```
let duration = time.duration.seconds(90500);
let latest_time = time.latest();
const timeAdvance = web3.utils.toBN(currenBlockTS).add(latest_time)
await time.increaseTo(timeAdvance);
```

When I ran the test, I got the following errors,

> Error: The method evm_increaseTime does not exist/is not available at
> WebsocketSubprovider._handleSocketMessage
> (node_modules@trufflesuite\web3-provider-engine\subproviders\websocket.js:121:18)
> at WebSocket.onMessage (node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16) at
> WebSocket.emit (node:events:527:28) at Receiver.receiverOnMessage
> (node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:720:20) at Receiver.emit
> (node:events:527:28) at Receiver.dataMessage
> (node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:414:14) at
> C:\Users\User\Documents\blockchain\jb_lottery\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:371:23
> at
> C:\Users\User\Documents\blockchain\jb_lottery\node_modules\ws\lib\permessage-deflate.js:307:9
> at
> C:\Users\User\Documents\blockchain\jb_lottery\node_modules\ws\lib\permessage-deflate.js:389:7
> at afterWrite (node:internal/streams/writable:497:5) at onwrite
> (node:internal/streams/writable:477:7) at Zlib.cb
> (node:internal/streams/transform:202:7) at Zlib.processCallback
> (node:zlib:611:8)
>
> Error: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field
> params.fromBlock of type string at
> WebsocketSubprovider._handleSocketMessage
> (node_modules@trufflesuite\web3-provider-engine\subproviders\websocket.js:121:18)
> at WebSocket.onMessage (node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16) at
> WebSocket.emit (node:events:527:28) at Receiver.receiverOnMessage
> (node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:720:20) at Receiver.emit
> (node:events:527:28) at Receiver.dataMessage
> (node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:414:14) at
> C:\Users\User\Documents\blockchain\jb_lottery\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:371:23
> at
> C:\Users\User\Documents\blockchain\jb_lottery\node_modules\ws\lib\permessage-deflate.js:307:9
> at
> C:\Users\User\Documents\blockchain\jb_lottery\node_modules\ws\lib\permessage-deflate.js:389:7
> at afterWrite (node:internal/streams/writable:497:5) at onwrite
> (node:internal/streams/writable:477:7) at Zlib.cb
> (node:internal/streams/transform:202:7) at Zlib.processCallback
> (node:zlib:611:8)

The network used is the rinkeby test network.

Comment: The method `evm_increaseTime` is available in testing clients like ganache.

Comment: Really! is there a way to test time-dependent smart contracts on rinkeby?

Comment: One option is to use fork with ganache, see this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/103184/how-does-the-ganache-cli-fork-work.